# which global variable is for last expression

Tags: ruby

Ruby Version - 1.9.2

In IRB the last expression is in _ . But if you  are in a ruby program
how to get the last expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't; save it in a variable.

[List of 1.9 special variables](http://ruby.wikia.com/wiki/Special_variable)

Comment: maybe it is the right thing...I guess I have use a variable to hold the value of the expression...I am thinking of side effect expression which might just throw a result